# Understanding numpy behavior when subsetting by negation of boolean vector

Tags: numpy

I am observing some strange behavior that I'm trying to understand.

Unfortunately, I don't have the specific example because I can't share my data.
With b I'm creating a 2d matrix with random boolean values.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.normal(size=(10000, 12, 1000))
p = 0.5
b = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(a.shape[0], a.shape[1]), p=[p, 1-p])

a[b].shape
(60037, 1000)

a[~b].shape
(59963, 1000)
```

This is all as we would expect to see.  However, in my actual dataset, where A also has 3 dimensions, and b is also a boolean 2-dimensional, when I subset

`a[~b].shape`

the result is a 2-dimensional vector with about 12x more rows in the 0th dimension. It's 1.61M X 11 for the output I have compared to the input dimension of (104529, 12, 11) for a and (104529, 12) for b.

When I subset on b, we do see something that looks sensible:

```
a[b].shape
(85472, 11)
```

Some evidence of the strange result:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is 1.61M, and not 1.16M?

Comment: Added screenshot for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is described in the [numpy indexing guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). Since your mask `b` has shape `(104529, 12)`, we can expect the result of `a[b]` to have at most `104529 * 12 = 1254348` entries, which would happen if the mask was True everywhere.

This value is bigger than 1168876, so your result is reasonable. In fact, it means that your mask `b` had exactly 1168876 `True` values inside it. Note how `1254348 - 1168876 = 85472`, which is the number of results you get when index with `~b` ;)